# Boolean data update with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I use rails 5.2.1 and mongoid 7.0.2

And I try to use toggle in user model

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :admin, type: Boolean, default: "false"
  has_many :categories

  def toggle!(field)
    send "#{field}=", !self.send("#{field}?")
    save :validation => false
  end
end
```

But when I try in console I have this error:

```
irb(main):003:0> user.toggle!(:admin)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):3
        1: from app/models/user.rb:7:in `toggle!'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `scope_stack' for Category:Class
Did you mean?  scopes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :admin, type: Boolean, default: "false"
  has_many :categories

  def toggle!(field)
    self[field] = !self[field]
    self.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

Do you still get the same issue with this implementation?